Creating linear sequence in manim
Please, how can I create the sequence,
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 up to 100 with three dots (...) at the end just to show that the sequence continues forever? All the numbers in the sequence should remain at the middle of scene after generation
Nothing much. Used chatGPT to generate the sequence but it keeps giving me this code which doesn't give me what i want.
from manim import *
class CountingNumbers(Scene):
def construct(self):
# Start with an empty string for the sequence
sequence = ""
    # Loop to update the sequence from 0 to 100
    for i in range(101):
        # Append the current number to the sequence
        if i == 0:
            sequence = str(i)
        else:
            sequence += ", " + str(i)
        
        # Dynamically adjust the font size
        font_size = max(72 - i*0.5, 20)  # Decrease font size gradually but keep it readable
        
        # Create a new LaTeX text object for the updated sequence
        sequence_display = MathTex(sequence, font_size=font_size)
        
        # Center the sequence text on the screen
        sequence_display.move_to(ORIGIN)
        
        # Display the updated sequence
        self.clear()
        self.add(sequence_display)
        
        # Pause briefly to show the new number
        self.wait(0.1)
    
    # Append three dots to indicate continuation
    sequence += ", ..."
    
    # Create a final LaTeX text object with the sequence and continuation
    final_display = MathTex(sequence, font_size=20)
    final_display.move_to(ORIGIN)
    
    # Display the final sequence
    self.clear()
    self.add(final_display)
    
    # Wait before ending the scene
    self.wait(2)

